# Pheatmap annotation colors and border

Tags: r, pheatmap

Pheatmap `library(pheatmap)` takes `annotation_colors`to add the header ID colors on the top of each heatmap column.

I want to add white as column header color with borders.
Border can be added by `border_color` but this function draws borders also to the whole heatmap.

Below is what I have done so far.

```
library(pheatmap)   
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame( matrix(sample(30), ncol = 5))
colnames(df)<-LETTERS[1:5]
subj<-c("P1", "P2","P3", "T1", "T2","T3")
rownames(df)<-subj
aka2 = data.frame(ID = factor(rep(c("Pat","Trea"), each=3)))
rownames(aka2)<-subj
aka3 = list(ID = c(Pat = "white", Trea="blue"))
pheatmap(t(scale(df)),
         annotation_col = aka2, 
         annotation_colors = aka3[1],
         annotation_legend = FALSE,
         gaps_col =  3,
         show_colnames = T, show_rownames = T, cluster_rows = F, 
         cluster_cols = F, legend = TRUE, 
         clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean", border_color = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example showing how far you got.

Comment: Your code is showing that you are trying to display `ID` as black or blue not white. The `ID` annotation row is white because the rownames of `aka2` do not match the rownames of `df`. Also, if I remove `border_color` option from your example, the `ID` annotation row has a grey border surrounding white. So, on multiple levels, your question does not make sense. Please clarify your question/problem.

Comment: I have rephrased and clarified better the question

Comment: You say "but the color space remain empty." What do you expect to happen? Do you want Pat IDs to be white and Trea IDs to be blue? If so, reread my comment above; you need to set the rownames of `aka2` to that of `df`.

Comment: Yes, you are right,  I missed that part in this version. Now you can see 3 heatmap columns are blue and 3 are white; borders are needed to distinguish white labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use `grid` functions to edit the relevant grob:

```
library(pheatmap)   
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame( matrix(sample(30), ncol = 5))
colnames(df)<-LETTERS[1:5]
subj<-c("P1", "P2","P3", "T1", "T2","T3")
rownames(df)<-subj
aka2 = data.frame(ID = factor(rep(c("Pat","Trea"), each=3)))
rownames(aka2)<-subj
aka3 = list(ID = c(Pat = "white", Trea="blue"))

pheatmap(t(scale(df)),
         annotation_col = aka2, 
         annotation_colors = aka3[1],
         annotation_legend = FALSE,
         gaps_col =  3,
         show_colnames = T, show_rownames = T, cluster_rows = F, 
         cluster_cols = F, legend = TRUE, 
         clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean", border_color = FALSE)

# Edit the relevant grob
library(grid)
grid.ls(grid.force()) # "col_annotation" looks like it's the one to edit
grid.gedit("col_annotation", gp = gpar(col="grey70"))
```

Applying `grid.gget("col_annotation")$gp` to the original heatmap shows that `col_annotation` does have a `gp` slot with `fill` set but no `col`. After the edit, both `fill` and `col` are set.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I tried very hard to edit the `grobs` to add border color only on the annotations, but I think the only way is to modify the `pheatmap` function as well as the underlying `heatmap_motor`. Here is the `pheatmap2` and `heatmap_motor2` functions. The only changes is that `pheatmap2` calls `heatmap_motor2` and this line `border_color="gray"` in `heatmap_motor2`. You can find it about 2/3 of the way in `heatmap_motor2`.

**pheatmap2**

```
pheatmap2 <-function (mat, color = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 7,
    name = "RdYlBu")))(100), kmeans_k = NA, breaks = NA, border_color = "grey60",
    cellwidth = NA, cellheight = NA, scale = "none", cluster_rows = TRUE,
    cluster_cols = TRUE, clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean",
    clustering_distance_cols = "euclidean", clustering_method = "complete",
    clustering_callback = identity2, cutree_rows = NA, cutree_cols = NA,
    treeheight_row = ifelse(cluster_rows, 50, 0), treeheight_col = ifelse(cluster_cols,
        50, 0), legend = TRUE, legend_breaks = NA, legend_labels = NA,
    annotation_row = NA, annotation_col = NA, annotation = NA,
    annotation_colors = NA, annotation_legend = TRUE, drop_levels = TRUE,
    show_rownames = T, show_colnames = T, main = NA, fontsize = 10,
    fontsize_row = fontsize, fontsize_col = fontsize, display_numbers = F,
    number_format = "%.2f", number_color = "grey30", fontsize_number = 0.8 *
        fontsize, gaps_row = NULL, gaps_col = NULL, labels_row = NULL,
    labels_col = NULL, filename = NA, width = NA, height = NA,
    silent = FALSE, ...)
{
    if (is.null(labels_row)) {
        labels_row = rownames(mat)
    }
    if (is.null(labels_col)) {
        labels_col = colnames(mat)
    }
    mat = as.matrix(mat)
    if (scale != "none") {
        mat = scale_mat(mat, scale)
        if (is.na2(breaks)) {
            breaks = generate_breaks(mat, length(color), center = T)
        }
    }
    if (!is.na(kmeans_k)) {
        km = kmeans(mat, kmeans_k, iter.max = 100)
        mat = km$centers
        t = table(km$cluster)
        labels_row = sprintf("Cluster: %s Size: %d", names(t),
            t)
    }
    else {
        km = NA
    }
    if (is.matrix(display_numbers) | is.data.frame(display_numbers)) {
        if (nrow(display_numbers) != nrow(mat) | ncol(display_numbers) !=
            ncol(mat)) {
            stop("If display_numbers provided as matrix, its dimensions have to match with mat")
        }
        display_numbers = as.matrix(display_numbers)
        fmat = matrix(as.character(display_numbers), nrow = nrow(display_numbers),
            ncol = ncol(display_numbers))
        fmat_draw = TRUE
    }
    else {
        if (display_numbers) {
            fmat = matrix(sprintf(number_format, mat), nrow = nrow(mat),
                ncol = ncol(mat))
            fmat_draw = TRUE
        }
        else {
            fmat = matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(mat), ncol = ncol(mat))
            fmat_draw = FALSE
        }
    }
    if (cluster_rows) {
        tree_row = cluster_mat(mat, distance = clustering_distance_rows,
            method = clustering_method)
        tree_row = clustering_callback(tree_row, mat)
        mat = mat[tree_row$order, , drop = FALSE]
        fmat = fmat[tree_row$order, , drop = FALSE]
        labels_row = labels_row[tree_row$order]
        if (!is.na(cutree_rows)) {
            gaps_row = find_gaps(tree_row, cutree_rows)
        }
        else {
            gaps_row = NULL
        }
    }
    else {
        tree_row = NA
        treeheight_row = 0
    }
    if (cluster_cols) {
        tree_col = cluster_mat(t(mat), distance = clustering_distance_cols,
            method = clustering_method)
        tree_col = clustering_callback(tree_col, t(mat))
        mat = mat[, tree_col$order, drop = FALSE]
        fmat = fmat[, tree_col$order, drop = FALSE]
        labels_col = labels_col[tree_col$order]
        if (!is.na(cutree_cols)) {
            gaps_col = find_gaps(tree_col, cutree_cols)
        }
        else {
            gaps_col = NULL
        }
    }
    else {
        tree_col = NA
        treeheight_col = 0
    }
    attr(fmat, "draw") = fmat_draw
    if (!is.na2(legend_breaks) & !is.na2(legend_labels)) {
        if (length(legend_breaks) != length(legend_labels)) {
            stop("Lengths of legend_breaks and legend_labels must be the same")
        }
    }
    if (is.na2(breaks)) {
        breaks = generate_breaks(as.vector(mat), length(color))
    }
    if (legend & is.na2(legend_breaks)) {
        legend = grid.pretty(range(as.vector(breaks)))
        names(legend) = legend
    }
    else if (legend & !is.na2(legend_breaks)) {
        legend = legend_breaks[legend_breaks >= min(breaks) &
            legend_breaks <= max(breaks)]
        if (!is.na2(legend_labels)) {
            legend_labels = legend_labels[legend_breaks >= min(breaks) &
                legend_breaks <= max(breaks)]
            names(legend) = legend_labels
        }
        else {
            names(legend) = legend
        }
    }
    else {
        legend = NA
    }
    mat = scale_colours(mat, col = color, breaks = breaks)
    if (is.na2(annotation_col) & !is.na2(annotation)) {
        annotation_col = annotation
    }
    if (!is.na2(annotation_col)) {
        annotation_col = annotation_col[colnames(mat), , drop = F]
    }
    if (!is.na2(annotation_row)) {
        annotation_row = annotation_row[rownames(mat), , drop = F]
    }
    annotation = c(annotation_row, annotation_col)
    annotation = annotation[unlist(lapply(annotation, function(x) !is.na2(x)))]
    if (length(annotation) != 0) {
        annotation_colors = generate_annotation_colours(annotation,
            annotation_colors, drop = drop_levels)
    }
    else {
        annotation_colors = NA
    }
    if (!show_rownames) {
        labels_row = NULL
    }
    if (!show_colnames) {
        labels_col = NULL
    }
    gt = heatmap_motor2(mat, border_color = border_color, cellwidth = cellwidth,
        cellheight = cellheight, treeheight_col = treeheight_col,
        treeheight_row = treeheight_row, tree_col = tree_col,
        tree_row = tree_row, filename = filename, width = width,
        height = height, breaks = breaks, color = color, legend = legend,
        annotation_row = annotation_row, annotation_col = annotation_col,
        annotation_colors = annotation_colors, annotation_legend = annotation_legend,
        main = main, fontsize = fontsize, fontsize_row = fontsize_row,
        fontsize_col = fontsize_col, fmat = fmat, fontsize_number = fontsize_number,
        number_color = number_color, gaps_row = gaps_row, gaps_col = gaps_col,
        labels_row = labels_row, labels_col = labels_col, ...)
    if (is.na(filename) & !silent) {
        grid.newpage()
        grid.draw(gt)
    }
    invisible(list(tree_row = tree_row, tree_col = tree_col,
        kmeans = km, gtable = gt))
}
```

**heatmap_motor2**

```
heatmap_motor2 <-function (matrix, border_color, cellwidth, cellheight, tree_col,
    tree_row, treeheight_col, treeheight_row, filename, width,
    height, breaks, color, legend, annotation_row, annotation_col,
    annotation_colors, annotation_legend, main, fontsize, fontsize_row,
    fontsize_col, fmat, fontsize_number, number_color, gaps_col,
    gaps_row, labels_row, labels_col, ...)
{
    lo = lo(coln = labels_col, rown = labels_row, nrow = nrow(matrix),
        ncol = ncol(matrix), cellwidth = cellwidth, cellheight = cellheight,
        treeheight_col = treeheight_col, treeheight_row = treeheight_row,
        legend = legend, annotation_col = annotation_col, annotation_row = annotation_row,
        annotation_colors = annotation_colors, annotation_legend = annotation_legend,
        main = main, fontsize = fontsize, fontsize_row = fontsize_row,
        fontsize_col = fontsize_col, gaps_row = gaps_row, gaps_col = gaps_col,
        ...)
    res = lo$gt
    mindim = lo$mindim
    if (!is.na(filename)) {
        if (is.na(height)) {
            height = convertHeight(gtable_height(res), "inches",
                valueOnly = T)
        }
        if (is.na(width)) {
            width = convertWidth(gtable_width(res), "inches",
                valueOnly = T)
        }
        r = regexpr("\\.[a-zA-Z]*$", filename)
        if (r == -1)
            stop("Improper filename")
        ending = substr(filename, r + 1, r + attr(r, "match.length"))
        f = switch(ending, pdf = function(x, ...) pdf(x, ...),
            png = function(x, ...) png(x, units = "in", res = 300,
                ...), jpeg = function(x, ...) jpeg(x, units = "in",
                res = 300, ...), jpg = function(x, ...) jpeg(x,
                units = "in", res = 300, ...), tiff = function(x,
                ...) tiff(x, units = "in", res = 300, compression = "lzw",
                ...), bmp = function(x, ...) bmp(x, units = "in",
                res = 300, ...), stop("File type should be: pdf, png, bmp, jpg, tiff"))
        f(filename, height = height, width = width)
        gt = heatmap_motor(matrix, cellwidth = cellwidth, cellheight = cellheight,
            border_color = border_color, tree_col = tree_col,
            tree_row = tree_row, treeheight_col = treeheight_col,
            treeheight_row = treeheight_row, breaks = breaks,
            color = color, legend = legend, annotation_col = annotation_col,
            annotation_row = annotation_row, annotation_colors = annotation_colors,
            annotation_legend = annotation_legend, filename = NA,
            main = main, fontsize = fontsize, fontsize_row = fontsize_row,
            fontsize_col = fontsize_col, fmat = fmat, fontsize_number = fontsize_number,
            number_color = number_color, labels_row = labels_row,
            labels_col = labels_col, gaps_col = gaps_col, gaps_row = gaps_row,
            ...)
        grid.draw(gt)
        dev.off()
        return(gt)
    }
    if (mindim < 3)
        border_color = NA
    if (!is.na(main)) {
        elem = draw_main(main, fontsize = 1.3 * fontsize, ...)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 1, l = 3, name = "main")
    }
    if (!is.na2(tree_col) & treeheight_col != 0) {
        elem = draw_dendrogram(tree_col, gaps_col, horizontal = T)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 2, l = 3, name = "col_tree")
    }
    if (!is.na2(tree_row) & treeheight_row != 0) {
        elem = draw_dendrogram(tree_row, gaps_row, horizontal = F)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 4, l = 1, name = "row_tree")
    }
    elem = draw_matrix(matrix, border_color, gaps_row, gaps_col,
        fmat, fontsize_number, number_color)
    res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 4, l = 3, clip = "off",
        name = "matrix")
    if (length(labels_col) != 0) {
        pars = list(labels_col, gaps = gaps_col, fontsize = fontsize_col,
            ...)
        elem = do.call(draw_colnames, pars)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 5, l = 3, clip = "off",
            name = "col_names")
    }
    if (length(labels_row) != 0) {
        pars = list(labels_row, gaps = gaps_row, fontsize = fontsize_row,
            ...)
        elem = do.call(draw_rownames, pars)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 4, l = 4, clip = "off",
            name = "row_names")
    }
    if (!is.na2(annotation_col)) {
        converted_annotation = convert_annotations(annotation_col,
            annotation_colors)
        elem = draw_annotations(converted_annotation, border_color="gray", #Modified here
            gaps_col, fontsize, horizontal = T)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 3, l = 3, clip = "off",
            name = "col_annotation")
        elem = draw_annotation_names(annotation_col, fontsize,
            horizontal = T)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 3, l = 4, clip = "off",
            name = "row_annotation_names")
    }
    if (!is.na2(annotation_row)) {
        converted_annotation = convert_annotations(annotation_row,
            annotation_colors)
        elem = draw_annotations(converted_annotation, border_color,
            gaps_row, fontsize, horizontal = F)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 4, l = 2, clip = "off",
            name = "row_annotation")
        if (length(labels_col) != 0) {
            elem = draw_annotation_names(annotation_row, fontsize,
                horizontal = F)
            res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = 5, l = 2, clip = "off",
                name = "row_annotation_names")
        }
    }
    annotation = c(annotation_col[length(annotation_col):1],
        annotation_row[length(annotation_row):1])
    annotation = annotation[unlist(lapply(annotation, function(x) !is.na2(x)))]
    if (length(annotation) > 0 & annotation_legend) {
        elem = draw_annotation_legend(annotation, annotation_colors,
            border_color, fontsize = fontsize, ...)
        t = ifelse(is.null(labels_row), 4, 3)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = t, l = 6, b = 5,
            clip = "off", name = "annotation_legend")
    }
    if (!is.na2(legend)) {
        elem = draw_legend(color, breaks, legend, fontsize = fontsize,
            ...)
        t = ifelse(is.null(labels_row), 4, 3)
        res = gtable_add_grob(res, elem, t = t, l = 5, b = 5,
            clip = "off", name = "legend")
    }
    return(res)
}
```

It is then important to add these two new functions to the `pheatmap` environment. `pheatmap` uses functions that can only be found in it's own environment.

```
environment(pheatmap2) <- asNamespace('pheatmap')
environment(heatmap_motor2) <- asNamespace('pheatmap')
```

With the gray borders to the annotations using `pheatmap2`:

```
library(pheatmap)
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame( matrix(sample(30), ncol = 5))
colnames(df)<-LETTERS[1:5]
subj<-c("P1", "P2","P3", "T1", "T2","T3")
rownames(df)<-subj
aka2 = data.frame(ID = factor(rep(c("Pat","Trea"), each=3)))
rownames(aka2)<-subj
aka3 = list(ID = c(Pat = "white", Trea="blue"))
pheatmap2(t(scale(df)),
         annotation_col = aka2,
         annotation_colors = aka3[1], #aka3[1]
         annotation_legend = FALSE,
         gaps_col =  3,
         show_colnames = T, show_rownames = T, cluster_rows = F,
         cluster_cols = F, legend = TRUE,
         clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean", border_color = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: i have similar question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73007145/factorminer-plot-hcpc-function-for-cluster-labeling which is what you have done here modifying the function

Answer (score 6):

**Pheatmap annotation_col/annotation_row and borders and annotation_colors**

Just to make a few comments that may be a bit off the topic here, but relevant in the context of this question and might save someone some trouble.

1. If you are interested in having borders for all cells in the heatmap after setting annotation_col or annotation_row you must specify explicitly cellheight and cellwidth above certain levels (I used cellwidth = 3, cellheight=12).
2. The syntax for annotation_color is somewhat complex and requires a list of named vectors with named components. For example:

   ```
   annotation_col = data.frame("Cell_of_Origin"=factor(dta.disc$cell.origin,exclude=NULL,labels=c("GCB","non_GCB","Unclassifiable")))
   rownames(annotation_col)=dta.disc$id
   annotation_colors = list(Cell_of_Origin=c(GCB="red",non_GCB="green",Unclassifiable="yellow"))[1]
   ```

Where Cell_of_Origin is my annotation_col variable and GCB,non_GCB, Unclassifiable are the levels of the factor.

3. It seems strange to me to add a grid for annotated classes and not grid for the clusters (i.e. the subclasses may be distributed 'weirdly' within the clusters). One option I played with was to generate a dendrogram for each subclass separately and then merge the dendrograms together. In such a case you could add gaps between clusters using the cutree_cols / cutree_row options.The results weren't great but this might be a direction to explore.

   ```
   dend_gcb = reorder(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(as.matrix(t(dta.disc[dta.disc$cell.origin=="gcb",vars_reduced]))))),agglo.FUN=mean)
   dend_ngcb = reorder(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(as.matrix(t(dta.disc[dta.disc$cell.origin=="non-gcb",vars_reduced]))))),agglo.FUN=mean)
   dend_uncls =reorder(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(as.matrix(t(dta.disc[is.na(dta.disc$cell.origin),vars_reduced]))))),agglo.FUN=mean)
   dend=merge(merge(dend_gcb,dend_ngcb),dend_uncls)
   ```